# How to create summed variables using object values from List of objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an class

```
class Test(val first: Int, val second: Int, val third: Int)
```

Class Test may have other attributes than first, second, and third.

And I have a list:

```
val list: List[Test] = List(new Test(0,1,2), new Test(1,14,2), new Test(7,15,2))
```

How would I use foldLeft here to add together all first`s, second's, third's together to end up with variables:

allFirsts = 8

allSeconds = 30

allThirds = 6

I already have something like this worked out:

```
val (totalFirsts, totalSeconds, totalThirds) = list.foldLeft(0, 0, 0){ (sum, l) => (sum._1 + l.first , sum._2 + l.second, sum._3 + l.third) }
```

It seems to work fine, but I don't like the readability of _1, _2, and _3.  Maybe I can use `case` here to decompose values but I am just not sure how to make it all work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, tuple indexing can be a bit clunky. In this case you can use pattern matching instead.

```
val (totalFirsts, totalSeconds, totalThirds) =
  list.foldLeft(0, 0, 0){case ((a,b,c), test) =>
    (a+test.first, b+test.second, c+test.third)}
```

But the syntax can be streamlined even further. If your `Test` class were a `case class` then it would have an extractor you could use in the pattern match.

```
case class Test(first: Int, second: Int, third: Int)
. . .
val (totalFirsts, totalSeconds, totalThirds) =
  list.foldLeft(0, 0, 0){case ((a,b,c), Test(f,s,t)) => (a+f, b+s, c+t)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define another case class to hold the initial and final result, then you can use `first, second, third` instead of `_1, _2, _3`:

```
case class Test1(val first: Int, val second: Int, val third: Int)

list.foldLeft(Test1(0,0,0))((acc, t) => Test1(acc.first + t.first, acc.second + t.second, acc.third + t.third))
// res0: Test1 = Test1(8,30,6)
```

Comment: The only reason I would be against this solution is because class Test may have other attributes than first, second, and third that I wouldn't want to worry about instantiating.

Comment: The case class doesn't have to be the same as the `Test` class. Define another case class that has only three fields. *Test1* for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use it but it works

```
  case class Test3(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int)
  case class Test4(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int, a4: Int)

  import scala.reflect._
  def doMagic[T <: Product : ClassTag](data: List[T]): T ={
    val params: Seq[Object] = data.map(_.productIterator.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int]))
      .reduce((buffer, next) => buffer.zip(next).map { case (i, j) => i + j }).map(_.asInstanceOf[Object])
    classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(params:_*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
  doMagic(List(Test3(1,2,3), Test3(2,3,4), Test3(10,20,30))) // Test3(13,25,37)
  doMagic(List(Test4(1,2,3,5), Test4(2,3,4,0), Test4(10,20,30,100))) // Test4(13,25,37,105)
```

Do not forget to use reduceOption instead of reduce to handle empty lists. Here is used reduce to simplify code